# Change TextView align programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My `RelativeLayout` is like this :

`ImageView`(arrow back) `TextView`(title) `ImageButton`(close button)

- the first `ImageView` is just an arrow
- the `TextView` can change and must stay between the two image
- the second `ImageView` is a close button

I'm trying to change the visibility of the first image to GONE or VISIBLE

For this I need to update the layout param of the `TextView`, but this is not working properly

Here is my method :

```
private void setBackButton(boolean visible) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mTitle.getLayoutParams();
        if (visible) {
            mImageArrowBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.fragment_back);
        } else {
            mImageArrowBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        }
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.fragment_close);
        mTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

The arrow back is GONE and VISIBLE with no problem but the textview just stack on it. RIGHT_OF is not working.

Any idea ?

The complete layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_title_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_back"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_favorite"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_list_country_close"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fragment_close"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_favorite"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you're changing between GONE and VISIBLE, you shouldn't need to change the layout at all.  The framework should handle that for you.  What effect are you trying for in each state, and what are you getting?

Comment: Showing your XML layout for this setup may help make things more clear.

Comment: i just added the layout

Comment: i want the arrow to be GONE or VISIBLE and the textview be alignParentLeft if the arrow is gone or toRightOf if the arrow is VISIBLE. At first i call the method to make the arrow disapear (that's why in the xml the textview is alignParentLeft)

Comment: if i change ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT to ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT in params.addRule the textview align itself correctly with the left image when it appear. But when it disapear i need ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT when the image is GONE :/ this makes no sense at all

Comment: post the screen what you want..

Comment: @Yume117 Gabe Sechan is right. You don't need to do anything. Just change the visibility of the back image.

Comment: The textview must be align to something, when the imageview is GONE it's layout is not inflated so the textview can't align to it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to programmatically change the layout params of the TextView, use `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` instead. RelativeLayout will move the TextView to align it parentLeft when you make the first ImageView `GONE`.

Write your TextView like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_back"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_close"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

If this is NOT what you intended and you want the TextView to remain centered when you move the ImageView, then the solution is even simpler: set the ImageView's visibility to `INVISIBLE`, not `GONE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just set your layout like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_title_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Title" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fragment_close"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And change the visibility of mImageArrowBack programatically, it will work.

When the `ImageView` is GONE its layout is not inflated, but the reference to the View is kept. So the `TextView` aligns to the left of your layout in that case.